# Disassembly of a soldering station - dangers?

Tags: components, soldering-iron-station

I recently came into possession of an old soldering station. It doesn't work very well - the tip doesn't get hot enough to melt solder, so it'ls pretty useless. I've opened it up to strip it for parts. It contains very few - a nice illuminated switch I can make use of, a large transformer and a 470nF 250V poly capacitor. Is it safe to just go ahead and desolder these parts?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If the power is disconnected, yes.

Comment: Just make sure the cap is discharged.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't just need a new tip?

Comment: The station makes a loud ticking sound when it's on, which concerns me a little, and I'd rather not use it.

Comment: Are you sure that's not a thermostat cutting in and out? A photo, make and model seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: Images added, please let me know what you think. Can't see anything that looks like a thermostat.

Comment: Thermostat is inside heater of wand.  Most likely ok except tip is thermally corroded and needs tighter connection, cleaning etc.

Comment: The RS (RadioSpares) brand is good although that's a simple AC PSU. It is isolated from the mains and provides an earth connection to the iron. At 24 V AC you are safe. It seems as though the iron is the problem. RS sell Antex 24 V AC irons - but they don't have any temperature control.

Comment: The iron it came with is a Weller - 24V, 45W. Is that well matched?